# remove header from csv while reading from from txt or csv file in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to remove header from given input file. But I couldn't make it.
Th is what I have written. Can someone help me how to remove headers from the txt or csv file.

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

object SalesAmount {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName(getClass.getName).setMaster("local")

    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    val salesRDD = sc.textFile(args(0),2)

    val salesPairRDD = salesRDD.map(rec => {
      val fieldArr = rec.split(",")
      (fieldArr(1), fieldArr(3).toDouble)
    })

    val totalAmountRDD = salesPairRDD.reduceByKey(_+_).sortBy(_._2,false)



    val discountAmountRDD = totalAmountRDD.map(t => {
      if (t._2 > 1000) (t._1,t._2 * 0.9)
      else t
    })

    discountAmountRDD.foreach(println)


  }

}
```

Comment: Spark has a built-in CSV file reader in the DataFrame API (Spark SQL) that understands that those files may have headers, so you don't need to parse the text yourself. Also, the RDD API is now deprecated for end-user use and it is recommended that you use the DataFrame API.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Now this is not possible using RDD

Comment: It is possible, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skipping the first row when manually parsing text files using the RDD API is a bit tricky:

```
val salesPairRDD =
  salesRDD
    .mapPartitionsWithIndex((i, it) => if (i == 0) it.drop(1) else it)
    .map(rec => {
      val fieldArr = rec.split(",")
      (fieldArr(1), fieldArr(3).toDouble)
    })
```

The header line will be the first item in the first partition, so `mapPartitionsWithIndex` is used to iterate over the partitions and to skip the first item if the partition index is `0`.